# Unresolved type EnvironmentPlugin

Tags: webpack

[image]

This is in my webpack 5 module.export config. Not sure whats going on.

Comment: Can you post a minimal reproducible example? If not it would be helpful to at least know what types you have installed and configured.

Comment: Looks like webpacks builtin plugins dont work... I have const webpack = require("webpack") defined at the top of my config. Eachone gives me an unresolved type error.

Comment: We still don’t have enough information. Please post a reproducible example.